# How to efficiently iterate through rows in a large matrix with too many columns?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, data-science, distance-matrix

I'm working on document clustering where I first build a distance matrix from the tf-idf results. I use the below code to get my tf-idf matrix:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words={'english'})
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(models)
```

This results in a matrix of (9069, 22210). Now I want to build a distance matrix from this (9069*9069). I'm using the following code for that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
from scipy.spatial import distance

arrX = X.toarray()

rowSize = X.shape[0]
distMatrix = np.zeros(shape=(rowSize, rowSize))


#build distance matrix
for i, x in enumerate(arrX):
    for j, y in enumerate(arrX):   
        distMatrix[i][j] = distance.braycurtis(x, y)

np.savetxt("dist.csv", distMatrix, delimiter=",")
```

The problem with this code is that it's extremely slow for this matrix size. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: As long as `distance.braycurtis` only works with individual `x,y` rows there isn't much you can do better.  Calling it `rowsize**2` times is the main time consumer.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue is that the algorithms runs in `O(n^3)` since each iteration to `distance.braycurtis` requires the computation of two arrays of size 9069. Since the computation is done 9069*9069 times. This means **thousands billion scalar operations** are required so to complete the computation. This is huge. The thing is the complexity of the algorithm probably cannot be improved. There are several ways to speed this up:

The first thing to do is **not to recompute the distance twice**. Indeed, this distance seems to be a commutative operator so `distMatrix[i][j] == distMatrix[j][i]`. You can compute the upper triangular part and then copy it to the lower triangular part.

Another optimization is simply **not to use `distance.braycurtis`** because it is slow: it takes about 10 us/call on my machine. This is mainly because it creates several *temporary arrays*, is mostly *memory-bound* because of Numpy operations, and also because `np.sum` is not very fast (mainly because it uses of a pretty precise algorithm that is hard to optimize). Moreover, it is sequential while nearly all mainstream processor have multiple cores nowadays. We can use **Numba** so to massively speed up this operation:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(['float32(float32[::1], float32[::1])', 'float64(float64[::1], float64[::1])'], fastmath=True)
def fastBrayCurtis(arr1, arr2):
    assert arr1.size == arr2.size
    assert arr1.size > 0
    zero = arr1[0] * 0 # Trick to set `zero` to the right type regarding the one of `arr1`
    df, sm = zero, zero
    for k in range(arr1.size):
        df += np.abs(arr1[k] - arr2[k])
        sm += np.abs(arr1[k] + arr2[k])
    return df / sm

# The signature of the function is provided so to compile the function eagerly
# with both 32-bit and 64-bit floating-point 2D contiguous arrays.
@nb.njit(['float32[:,::1](float32[:,::1])', 'float64[:,::1](float64[:,::1])'], fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def brayCurtisDistMatrix(arr):
    n = arr.shape[0]
    distance = np.empty((n, n), dtype=arr.dtype)

    # Compute the distance matrix in parallel while balancing the work between threads
    for i in nb.prange((n+1)//2):
        # Top of the upper triangular part (many items)
        for j in range(i, n):
            distance[j, i] = distance[i, j] = fastBrayCurtis(arr[i], arr[j])
        # Bottom of the upper triangular part (few items)
        for j in range(n-1-i, n):
            distance[j, n-1-i] = distance[n-1-i, j] = fastBrayCurtis(arr[n-1-i], arr[j])

    return distance
```

This code is about **440 times faster** than the initial one on my 6-core i5-9600KF processor. Actually, a quick theoretical analysis combined with profiling results shows that the algorithm is close to be optimal (>75% of the computing power of my processor is used)! If this is not enough, you should consider using the simple-precision implementation. If this is still not enough, you should then also consider writing an optimized GPU code for that (or simply reconsider the need to compute such a huge distance matrix).

Comment: That's indeed a good explanation! What's the point with the assert in brayCurtisDistMatrix function? I commented it out and tried with a simple matrix and it seems the code works on my machine. I'm now going to feed it a large one and see how fast it runs.

Comment: This assertions are there just to avoid crashes when the matrix is not square (ie. make the code safer). Note a Numba crash stop the Python process with no exception nor fallback code so it can be dangerous in a large application. Such assertions can also sometime help the compiler to produce a faster code.

Comment: Ok, I see the point about assertions, but here I think it is not necessary to check for a square matrix, because the input matrix may have different number of rows and columns. Or am I wrong about it?

Comment: Ha you are right, it can also work for non-square matrices. The assertion seems not needed in the end.

Answer (score -1):

You see, the individual elements of the NumPy multidimensional matrix you give in as input are saved in memory in 2 ways. They are:
ROW MAJOR
COLUMN MAJOR
Each has its advantages and disadvantages.
You can even control the way it is stored.
I hope you find this helpful

Comment: No. Calls to `distance.braycurtis` take more than 99% of the time. The access to arrays is done contiguously here. Thus, the access pattern of Numpy arrays is definitively not the problem.