# Speeding up vector distance calculation using Numba

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, numba

Below are some of the functions I wrote for distance (square) calculation in 3-D toroidal geometry for a collection of particles in that 3-D space:

```python
import itertools
import time
import numpy as np
import scipy
import numba
from numba import njit

@njit(cache=True)
def get_dr2(i=np.array([]),j=np.array([]),cellsize=np.array([])):
    k=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.float64)
    dr2=0.0
    for idx in numba.prange(cellsize.shape[0]):
        k[idx] = (j[idx]-i[idx])-cellsize[idx]*np.rint((j[idx]-i[idx])/cellsize[idx])
        dr2+=k[idx]**2
    return dr2


@numba.guvectorize(["void(float64[:],float64[:],float64[:],float64[:])"],
             "(m),(m),(m)->()",nopython=True,cache=True)
def get_dr2_vec(i,j,cellsize,dr2):
    dr2[:]=0.0
    k=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.float64)
    for idx in numba.prange(cellsize.shape[0]):
        k[idx] = (j[idx]-i[idx])-cellsize[idx]*np.rint((j[idx]-i[idx])/cellsize[idx])
        dr2[0]+=k[idx]**2


@njit(cache=True)
def pair_vec_gen(pIList=np.array([[]]),pJList=np.array([[]])):
    assert pIList.shape[1] == pJList.shape[1]
    vecI=np.zeros((pIList.shape[0]*pJList.shape[0],pIList.shape[1]))
    vecJ=np.zeros_like(vecI)
    for i in numba.prange(pIList.shape[0]):
        for j in numba.prange(pJList.shape[0]):
            for k in numba.prange(pIList.shape[1]):
                vecI[j+pJList.shape[0]*i][k]=pIList[i][k]
                vecJ[j+pJList.shape[0]*i][k]=pJList[j][k]

    return vecI,vecJ


@njit(cache=True)
def pair_vec_dist(pIList=np.array([[]]),pJList=np.array([[]]),cellsize=np.array([])):
    assert pIList.shape[1] == pJList.shape[1]
    vecI=np.zeros((pIList.shape[0]*pJList.shape[0],pIList.shape[1]))
    vecJ=np.zeros_like(vecI)
    r2List=np.zeros(vecI.shape[0])
    for i in numba.prange(pIList.shape[0]):
        for j in numba.prange(pJList.shape[0]):
            for k in numba.prange(pIList.shape[1]):
                vecI[j+pJList.shape[0]*i][k]=pIList[i][k]
                vecJ[j+pJList.shape[0]*i][k]=pJList[j][k]
    r2List=get_dr2_vec2(vecI,vecJ,cellsize)
    return r2List


@njit(cache=True)
def get_dr2_vec2(i=np.array([[]]),j=np.array([[]]),cellsize=np.array([])):
    dr2=np.zeros(i.shape[0],dtype=np.float64)
    k=np.zeros(i.shape[1],dtype=np.float64)
    for m in numba.prange(i.shape[0]):
        for n in numba.prange(i.shape[1]):
            k[n] = (j[m,n]-i[m,n])-cellsize[n]*np.rint((j[m,n]-i[m,n])/cellsize[n])
            dr2[m]+=k[n]**2
    return dr2


def pair_dist_calculator_cdist(pIList=np.array([[]]),pJList=np.array([[]]),cellsize=np.array([])):
    assert pIList.shape[1] == pJList.shape[1]
    r2List = (scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(pIList, pJList, metric=get_dr2_wrapper(cellsize=cellsize))).flatten()
    return np.array(r2List).flatten()

def get_dr2_wrapper(cellsize=np.array([])):
    return lambda u, v: get_dr2(u,v,cellsize)


frames=50
timedata=np.zeros((5,frames),dtype=np.float64)
N, dim = 100, 3  # 100 particles in 3D
cellsize=np.array([26.4,19.4,102.4])
for i in range(frames):
    
    print("\rIter {}".format(i),end='')
    vec = np.random.random((N, dim))
    
    rList1=[];rList2=[];rList3=[];rList4=[];rList5=[]
   
    #method 1
    #print("method 1")
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for (pI, pJ) in itertools.product(vec, vec):
        rList1.append(get_dr2(pI,pJ,cellsize))
    end =time.perf_counter()
    timedata[0,i]=(end-start)
    
    #method 2
    #print("method 2")
    pIvec=[];pJvec=[];rList2=[]
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for (pI, pJ) in itertools.product(vec, vec):
        pIvec.append(pI)
        pJvec.append(pJ)
    rList2=get_dr2_vec(np.array(pIvec),np.array(pJvec),cellsize)
    end =time.perf_counter()
    timedata[1,i]=(end-start)
    
    #method 3
    #print("method 3")
    start = time.perf_counter()
    rList3=get_dr2_vec(*pair_vec_gen(vec,vec),cellsize)
    end =time.perf_counter()
    timedata[2,i]=(end-start)
    
    #method 4
    #print("method 4")    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    rList4=pair_vec_dist(vec,vec,cellsize)
    end =time.perf_counter()
    timedata[3,i]=(end-start)

    #method 5
    #print("method 5")
    #start = time.perf_counter()
    #rList5=pair_dist_calculator_cdist(np.array(pIvec),np.array(pJvec),cellsize)
    #end =time.perf_counter()
    #timedata[4,i]=(end-start)
    
    assert (rList1 == rList2).all()
    assert (rList2 == rList3).all()
    assert (rList3 == rList4).all()
    #assert rList4 == rList5
       

print("\n")

for i in range(4):
    print("Method {} Average time {:.3g}s \u00B1 {:.3g}s".format(i+1,np.mean(timedata[i,1:]),np.std(timedata[i,1:])))

exit()
```

The essential idea is that at a particular time you have a snapshot of the particles or `frame` which contains the position of the particles. Now we can calculate all the distances between the particles we can use the following approaches:

1. Calculate distance between points iteratively in pure python; passing the combination of the position of the two particles one by one via `Numba`.
2. Create an iteration list (in pure python) beforehand and pass the whole list to a `Numba` `@guvectorize` function
3. Do (2) but all steps in `Numba`
4. Integrate all step in (3) to a simple `Numba` function
5. (optional) parse the positions to `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` with the distance function as the distance metric.

For 50 frames containing 100 particles we have the respective times (`frames, N = 50, 100`):

```
Method 1 Average time 0.017s ± 0.00555s
Method 2 Average time 0.0181s ± 0.00573s
Method 3 Average time 0.00182s ± 0.000944s
Method 4 Average time 0.000485s ± 0.000348s
```

For 50 frames containing 1000 particles we have the respective times (`frames, N = 50, 1000`):

```
Method 1 Average time 2.11s ± 0.977s
Method 2 Average time 2.42s ± 0.859s
Method 3 Average time 0.349s ± 0.12s
Method 4 Average time 0.0694s ± 0.022s
```

and for 1000 frames containing 100 particles we have the respective times (`frames, N = 1000, 100`):

```
Method 1 Average time 0.0244s ± 0.0166s
Method 2 Average time 0.0288s ± 0.0254s
Method 3 Average time 0.00258s ± 0.00231s
Method 4 Average time 0.000636s ± 0.00086s
```

(All the time shown above are after removing the contribution from the first iteration)
Method 5 simply fails due to memory requirements and is much slower in comparison to any other method

Given the above dataset, I tend to prefer Method 4 though I am a bit concerned about the average time increase when I increase `frames` from `50` to `1000`. Is there any further optimizations I can do in these implementations or if someone has ideas for much faster and memory conscious implementations? Any suggestions are welcome.

**Update**

Based on Jerome's answer the modified function is now:

```python
@njit(cache=True,parallel=True)
def pair_vec_dist(pIList=np.array([[]]),pJList=np.array([[]]),cellsize=np.array([])):
    assert pIList.shape[1] == pJList.shape[1]
    assert cellsize.size == 3
    dr2=np.zeros(pIList.shape[0]*pJList.shape[0],dtype=np.float64)
    inv_cellsize = 1.0 / cellsize
    for i in numba.prange(pIList.shape[0]):
        for j in range(pJList.shape[0]):
            offset = j + pJList.shape[0] * i
            xdist = pJList[j,0]-pIList[i,0]
            ydist = pJList[j,1]-pIList[i,1]
            zdist = pJList[j,2]-pIList[i,2]

            xk =  xdist-cellsize[0]*np.rint(xdist*inv_cellsize[0])
            yk =  ydist-cellsize[1]*np.rint(ydist*inv_cellsize[1])
            zk =  zdist-cellsize[2]*np.rint(zdist*inv_cellsize[2])

            dr2[offset] = xk**2+yk**2+zk**2
    return dr2
```

As Jerome pointed out that a very simple optimization could be running the loops through just the "lower half of the symmetric matrix" the distance calculation creates, though in a realistic situation I might have vector lists as `pI` and `pJ` where `pI` is a *subset* of `pJ`, which complicates this situation. Either I have to create two separate functions and control them via a wrapper function or somehow manage that in one single function. If there are any suggestions on how to do so that would be really helpful.

**Update 2**

I should clarify the problem furthermore. In this code I am trying to calculate distance between all points in a frame/snapshot, which is used further for pair distance distribution analysis. But in some cases we might want to focus on a subset of coordinates in a frame and calculate the distribution from their perspective. In such a case we select this subset `smallVec` from a pool of all coordinates `vec` (such that `smallVec +restOfVec = vec`)  and calculate `pair_vec_dist(smallVec,vec)` instead of `pair_vec_dist(vec,vec)`. For this calculation one can use `list(pair_vec_dist(smallVec,smallVec)).append(pair_vec_dist(smallVec,restOfVec)`.
Based on the discussion with Jerome, I modified my function as:

```python3
@njit(cache=True,parallel=True)
def pair_vec_dist_cmb(pIList=np.array([[]]),pJList=np.array([[]]),cellsize=np.array([]),is_sq=True,is_nonsq=True):
    assert pIList.shape[1] == pJList.shape[1]
    assert cellsize.size == 3

    dr2_1=0; dr2_2=0

    dr2_1=int(0.5*pIList.shape[0]*(pIList.shape[0]+1))

    if is_nonsq:
       dr2_2=int(pIList.shape[0]*pJList.shape[0])

    dr2 = np.zeros((dr2_1+dr2_2),dtype=np.float64)
    inv_cellsize = 1.0 / cellsize
    for j in numba.prange(0,pIList.shape[0],1):

        if is_sq:

           for i in range(j,pIList.shape[0],1):
               index_1 = int(0.5*i*(i+1)+j)
               xdist = pIList[j,0]-pIList[i,0]
               ydist = pIList[j,1]-pIList[i,1]
               zdist = pIList[j,2]-pIList[i,2]

               xk =  xdist-cellsize[0]*np.rint(xdist*inv_cellsize[0])
               yk =  ydist-cellsize[1]*np.rint(ydist*inv_cellsize[1])
               zk =  zdist-cellsize[2]*np.rint(zdist*inv_cellsize[2])

               dr2[index_1] = xk**2+yk**2+zk**2

        if is_nonsq:

           for j in range(pJList.shape[0]):
               index_2 = dr2_1+ j + pJList.shape[0] * i
               xdist = pJList[j,0]-pIList[i,0]
               ydist = pJList[j,1]-pIList[i,1]
               zdist = pJList[j,2]-pIList[i,2]

               xk =  xdist-cellsize[0]*np.rint(xdist*inv_cellsize[0])
               yk =  ydist-cellsize[1]*np.rint(ydist*inv_cellsize[1])
               zk =  zdist-cellsize[2]*np.rint(zdist*inv_cellsize[2])

               dr2[index_2] = xk**2+yk**2+zk**2

    return dr2
```

Where `pI` (size: `(N,3)`) is the subset of `pJ` (size `(M,3)`. In this code we subdivide the calculation into two sections: pair distance between pI-pI, which is symmetric and hence we can calculate only the lower triangular matrix i.e. `N(N-1)/2` unique values. The other section is pI-pJ distances where we have to go through `M(M-N)` unique values. To further optimize the function, I have two additional changes:

1. Combining the outer loop for both sections. In order to do so I am now iterating over the *upper* triangular matrix which translates to `N(N+1)/2` values. One can also implement an `if` check to see if coordinates are identical, though I am not sure how much time it would save.
2. To avoid appending the results from the two section together, I am predefining and partitioning the returned array by length.

A further assumption I have made is that time needed for partitioning `vec` into `smallVec` and `restOfVec` is negligent with respect to the pair distance calculation. Obviously, if wrong, one might need to rethink another optimization pathway.

The resultant function is **1.5** times faster than the previous function. I am looking to further optimize the function, but I am very new to loop tilling and other advanced optimizations, so if you have any suggestions, please let me know.

**Update 3**
So I figured that I should focus on making the function more optimized in terms of serial calculations as I might simply use `Dask` or `multiprocessing` to implement to work on multiple sections of an input collection of frames. So the reference function now is:

```python
@njit(cache=True,parallel=False, fastmath=True, boundscheck=False, nogil=True)
def pair_vec_dist_test(pIList,pJList,cellsize):

    _I=pIList.shape[0]
    _J=pJList.shape[0]

    dr2 = np.empty(int(_I*_J),dtype=np.float32)
    inv_cellsize = 1.0 / cellsize

    for i in numba.prange(pIList.shape[0]):
        for j in range(pJList.shape[0]):
            index = j + pJList.shape[0] * i
            xdist = pJList[j,0]-pIList[i,0]
            ydist = pJList[j,1]-pIList[i,1]
            zdist = pJList[j,2]-pIList[i,2]
            xk =  xdist-cellsize[0]*np.rint(xdist*inv_cellsize[0])
            yk =  ydist-cellsize[1]*np.rint(ydist*inv_cellsize[1])
            zk =  zdist-cellsize[2]*np.rint(zdist*inv_cellsize[2])
            dr2[index] = xk**2+yk**2+zk**2

    return dr2
```

Going back to the main problem while ignoring the symmetry aspect, I tried to further optimize the distance function as:

```python
@njit(cache=True,parallel=False, fastmath=True, boundscheck=False, nogil=True)
def pair_vec_dist_test_v2(pIList,pJList,cellsize):

    _I=pIList.shape[0]
    _J=pJList.shape[0]

    dr2 = np.empty(int(_I*_J),dtype=np.float32)
    inv_cellsize = 1.0 / cellsize

    tile=32
    
    
    for ii in range(0,_I,tile):
        for jj in range(0,_J,tile):
            for i in range(ii,min(_I,ii+tile)):
                for j in range(jj,min(_J,jj+tile)):
                    index = j + _J * i
                    xdist = pJList[j,0]-pIList[i,0]
                    ydist = pJList[j,1]-pIList[i,1]
                    zdist = pJList[j,2]-pIList[i,2]
                    xk =  xdist-cellsize[0]*np.rint(xdist*inv_cellsize[0])
                    yk =  ydist-cellsize[1]*np.rint(ydist*inv_cellsize[1])
                    zk =  zdist-cellsize[2]*np.rint(zdist*inv_cellsize[2])
                    dr2[index] = xk**2+yk**2+zk**2

    return dr2
```

which is essentially tiling up the two vector arrays. However I couldn't get any speedup as the exec time for both functions are roughly the same. I also thought about working with the *transpose* of the vector arrays, but I couldn't figure out how to align them in a loop when the vector lengths are not a multiple of tile length. Does anyone has any further suggestions or ideas on how to procced?

Edit: Another failed trial

```python
@njit(cache=True,parallel=False, fastmath=True, boundscheck=False, nogil=True)
def pair_vec_dist_test_v3(pIList,pJList,cellsize):
    
    inv_cellsize = 1.0 / cellsize
    
    tile=32
  
    _I=pIList.shape[0]
    _J=pJList.shape[0]

    vecI=np.empty((_I+2*tile,3),dtype=np.float64)     # for rolling effect
    vecJ=np.empty((_J+2*tile,3),dtype=np.float64)     # for rolling effect

    vecI_mask=np.ones((_I+2*tile),dtype=np.uint8)
    vecJ_mask=np.ones((_J+2*tile),dtype=np.uint8)

    vecI[:_I]=pIList
    vecJ[:_J]=pJList

    vecI[_I:]=0.
    vecJ[_J:]=0.

    vecI_mask[_I:]=0
    vecI_mask[_J:]=0

    #print(vecI,vecJ)

    ILim=_I+(tile-_I%tile)
    JLim=_J+(tile-_J%tile)
    
    dr2 = np.empty((ILim*JLim),dtype=np.float64)

    vecI=vecI.T
    vecJ=vecJ.T

    for ii in range(ILim):
        for jj in range(0,JLim,tile):
            index = jj + JLim*ii
            #print(ii,jj,index)
            mask  = np.multiply(vecJ_mask[jj:jj+tile],vecI_mask[ii:ii+tile])
            xdist = vecJ[0,jj:jj+tile]-vecI[0,ii:ii+tile]
            ydist = vecJ[1,jj:jj+tile]-vecI[1,ii:ii+tile]
            zdist = vecJ[2,jj:jj+tile]-vecI[2,ii:ii+tile]
            xk =  xdist-cellsize[0]*np.rint(xdist*inv_cellsize[0])
            yk =  ydist-cellsize[1]*np.rint(ydist*inv_cellsize[1])
            zk =  zdist-cellsize[2]*np.rint(zdist*inv_cellsize[2])
            arr = xk**2+yk**2+zk**2
            dr2[index:index+tile] = np.multiply(arr,mask)


    return dr2
```

Answer (score 3):

First things first: there are **races conditions** in your current code. This basically means the produced results can be corrupted (and it also impact performance). In practice, this causes an *undefined behaviour*. For example, `k[n]` is read by multiple thread in `get_dr2_vec2`. One need to be very careful when using `prange`. In this case, the race condition can be removed by just not using a temporary array which is not really useful and not using `prange` in the inner loop due to `dr2[m]` being updated (updating it from multiple threads also cause a race condition).

Moreover, `prange` is often not practically useful when `parallel=True` is not set in the Numba decorator. Indeed, the current functions are **not parallel** since this flag is missing.

Finally, you can merge the function `pair_vec_dist` and `get_dr2_vec2` and the internal loops so to **avoid creating and filling large temporary arrays**. Indeed, the RAM throughput is pretty small nowadays compared to the computing power of modern processor. This gap is getting bigger since the last two decades. This effect is called the "memory wall" and it is not expected to disappear any time soon. Codes less memory-bound generally tends to be faster and scale better.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
@njit(cache=True, parallel=True)
def pair_vec_dist(pIList=np.array([[]]),pJList=np.array([[]]),cellsize=np.array([])):
    assert pIList.shape[1] == pJList.shape[1]
    dr2=np.zeros(pIList.shape[0]*pJList.shape[0],dtype=np.float64)
    inv_cellsize = 1.0 / cellsize
    for i in numba.prange(pIList.shape[0]):
        for j in range(pJList.shape[0]):
            offset = j + pJList.shape[0] * i
            for k in range(pIList.shape[1]):
                tmp = pJList[j,k]-pIList[i,k]
                k = tmp-cellsize[k]*np.rint(tmp*inv_cellsize[k])
                dr2[offset] += k**2
    return dr2
```

It is **11 times faster** with `frames=50` and `N=1000` on my 6-core machine (i5-9600KF).

The code can be optimized further. For example, `dr2` is a flatten symmetric square matrix, so only the upper-right part needs to be computed and the bottom-left part can just be copied. Note that to do that efficiently in parallel, the work needs to be balanced between the thread (otherwise, the slowest will not be faster and will be the bottleneck). One can also generate an optimized version of the function only supporting `cellsize.size == 3`. Moreover, one can use *register tiling* so to make the code more cache-friendly. Finally, one can transpose the input so the layout is more SIMD-friendly (this certainly require the loop to be manually unrolled and the register tiling optimization to be done before).

Comment: Hi @Jerome, really thanks for great answer!  I have now modified the function and I have updated the question, but I couldn't really grasp the last two sentences in your answer. I thought that Numba does SIMD autovectorization. Can you help me apply this for my function?

Comment: For the load balancing required to get a parallel speed up, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253179/12939557). Regarding the auto-vectorization, Numba generate a low-level intermediate code provided to LLVL-Lite which is the JIT compiler of Numba. LLVM-Lite does perform such optimization but it often fail in non-trivial cases. This use-case is a non trivial one because the memory layout make things significantly more complex. This is why a transposition could help. I did not understand your point about `pI` and `pJ` in the edit.

Comment: In this code I am trying to calculate distance between all points in a frame, which is used further for pair distribution analysis. But in some cases we want to focus on a subset of coordinates in a frame and calculate pair distribution from their perspective. So we in such cases we select this subset `smallVec` from a pool of all coordinates `vec` and have to evaluate calculate `pair_vec_dist(smallVec,vec)` instead of  `pair_vec_dist(vec,vec)`. For this calculation one can use  `list(pair_vec_dist(smallVec,smallVec)).append(pair_vec_dist(smallVec,restOfVec))` .

Comment: This is most simplest idea I can think of to reduce the calculation load from N^2 to (n-1)*n/2 + (n-N)^2

Comment: Interesting. In this case, the optimization consisting to computing only the upper part is only possible if `pIList` is equal to `pJList`. The thing is if they are small vectors, then the optimization is not very interesting assuming the second operation (where the vector are different) is expensive (which is certainly the case since `restOfVec.size` should be significantly bigger than `smallVec.size` if my understanding is correct). This means this optimization may not actually worth it in this case. Reducing the complexity is a good idea.

Comment: I would have to probably implement two functions: one with the symmetric matrix idea and another one with brute force matrix-type operations, which would be largely similar but different in loop indices.  Now as you understand the scenario here, do you have any ideas on further optimization? The function in the updated question above would essentially be the prototype for these two functions.

Comment: Yes. The other optimizations about loop tiling, unrolling and changing the memory layout are still possible. Tiling is important if the code is rather memory bound and changing the memory layout is critical if the code is compute bound. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA) for more information about AoS vs SoA. Your current code basically use an AoS layout while the ideal layout is generally AoSoA (complex) and SoA should be faster (dependent of the target architecture). It is probably more interesting to apply such optimizations on the second function.

Comment: Hi @jérôme-richard, can you explain a bit more about your previous comment about loop tiling and changing the memory layout in terms of the python numba implementation. I tried writing down my function but I couldn't find any consistent guides on how to do such optimizations with python and numba. I am pretty new to code optimization and I looked at various optimizations, but I am not sure whether numba can be fine tuned to such specifications. The only clear examples I saw involved C++, so if you suggest how to rewrite this function in numba-python, that would be really helpful.

Comment: C++ and Numba behave similarly when it comes to optimizations (but not much for parallelism due to a restricted parallel model in Numba). Here, the idea is to add two i/j inner loops and add a stride in the current i/j outer loops. The stride has to be a compile-time constant for compiler optimizations to apply. Note that this will reduce the scalability of the operation so it might be slower on many-core systems. Usually, this can be fixed by collapsing the parallel loops but Numba cannot do that automatically yet. Note the resulting code will also be significantly less readable.